# Actionscript 3 - adding event listener to dynamically generated movieclip

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, adobe

So I have a game I'm working on where each level might have a different number of characters available, so I'm generating them with addChild and an array. I got the eventlistener to work on the stage, but now I made the “world” larger than the screen so I made everything on a parent movieClip. Now my eventlisteners aren’t working! The characters now disappear and reappear in the upper left corner! Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share a bit of your code.

Comment: a little bit of code would be useful.

Comment: This sounds like a world to game space issue, obviously we can't directly point to anything without seeing code but it seems that the internal 'character' logic could be interfering.